# mgo: Find fields of type number (int, float64) doesn't work

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I'm developing a RESTful API in go with the mgo driver for the MongoDB.

The problem is that I'm trying to fetch documents by a field of type int and no results is returned.

For example I have this document:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5797833e9de6f8c5615a20f9"),
  "id" : "28743915-9be0-427d-980d-5009bfe1b13a",
  "name" : "Hunter",
  "rating" : 2.9,
  "downloads" : 5040
}
```

And when trying to fetch this document with:

```
conn.Session.
    DB("face").
    C("papers").
    Find(bson.M{"rating": 2.9}).
    All(&papers) // papers is an instance of a slice struct.
```

It will not return any documents but doing the same in a mongo shell returns documents, for example:

```
db.papers.find({"rating": 2.9})
```

But doing this in the mongo shell won't return any documents:

```
db.papers.find({"rating": "2.9"})
```

So I think that the problem might be that when bson.M is being serialized it might convert the value to a string, because that bson.M is a *map[string]interface{}*

This is how the Paper struct looks like

```
type Paper struct {
    ID          string         `json:"id,omitempty" bson:"id"`
    Name        string         `json:"name,omitempty" bson:"name"`
    Rating      float64        `json:"rating" bson:"rating"`
    Downloads   int            `json:"downloads" bson:"downloads"`
}
```

Comment: Could you show us the declaration of struct of which `papers` is a slice?

Comment: Yes I can add it, but I don't think where the problem lies because it works if i try to find by name instead: bson.M{"name": "Hunter"}.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to understand what is your problem and can't. Most confusing part is your problem explanation

> 1. I'm trying to fetch documents by a field of type int
> 2. Find(bson.M{"rating": 2.9}).
> 3. "rating" : 2.9

In which world `2.9` is an integer?

1. There is no type `number` (which you have mentioned in title) nor in Go, nor in Mongo.
2. If you are inserting `float64` with `mgo` it's inserted into Mongo as [`double`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/#document-type-available-types)
3. You can't query `double` with `string` query. So `db.papers.find({"rating": 2.9})` returns documents and `db.papers.find({"rating": "2.9"})` - not, even if there are a few documents with `"rating": 2.9`.

There is no error in `mgo` nor in `mongo`. If you are interested, here is the sample code that inserts map and retrieves data with your `Paper` class:

```
package main

import (
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
    "fmt"
)

type Paper struct {
    ID          string         `json:"id,omitempty" bson:"id"`
    Name        string         `json:"name,omitempty" bson:"name"`
    Rating      float64        `json:"rating" bson:"rating"`
    Downloads   int            `json:"downloads" bson:"downloads"`
}

func main() {
    session, err := mgo.Dial("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/face")

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer session.Close()
    session.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)

    c := session.DB("face").C("papers")
    c.Insert(bson.M{
        "id": "28743915-9be0-427d-980d-5009bfe1b13a",
        "name": "Hunter",
        "rating": 2.9,
        "downloads": 5040,
    })

    var papers []Paper
    c.Find(bson.M{"rating": 2.9}).All(&papers) // equivalent of db.papers.find({"rating": 2.9})
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", papers)
}
```